# Hide the verbosity of a component system and provide a more elegant interface to the user in a generic way

Tags: c#, entity, components

I have an entity-component system that lets me make custom entities and assemble their functionality at runtime. This process consists of making new Entity instances and then adding component instances to them. The drawback is that now, every time I want to modify the X coordinate of the object I need to do, `obj.GetComponent<TransformComponent>().X` which is ugly.

I can of course make a class that extends Entity and has some fixed components added, and then add shorthands, in a form of properties, for those components so that when I want to change the X coordinate I just need to do `obj.Transform.X`. This will be my go to option if there's no better solution, however, I would much prefer if there was a generic way to add these shorthands to any subclass of Entity. For example, I could make an interface that was called ITransformable that defined the Transform property, but then every class would have to contain identical implementations of that property which is redundant.

Another option I considered is having interfaces but only using them as markers for extension methods. Then I could have a method called `Transform()` implemented as an extension method on ITransformable that gets the correct component. The problem with this is that I can't restrict the interfaces to only Entity classes so I have no access to the GetComponent method in my extension methods, also, `Transform().X` still looks pretty ugly. I could do some type casting but then it's seriously becoming a hack.

Is there any other sane option out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a solution for this earlier this year: [Components](https://bitbucket.org/Tamschi/components) and [ComponentEntities](https://bitbucket.org/Tamschi/componententities)

The relations between components are defined through annotated properties and methods, as seen [here](https://bitbucket.org/Tamschi/componenttest/src/12f5db2b9782821d483c0dc495311c18fc43a928/ComponentTest%20Main.cs?at=default):

```
// Link to component of type B through a property.
// The name doesn't matter.
[ComponentLink]
B B { get; set; }

// Called when components are added or removed.
// The parameter type acts as a filter.
[NotifyComponentLinked]
void Added(object o)
{ Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name + " linked to " + o.GetType().Name + "."); }
[NotifyComponentUnlinked]
void Removed(object o)
{ Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name + " unlinked from " + o.GetType().Name + "."); }

// Attaches to events in compenents of type D and E.
// Rewriting this with Lambda Expressions may be possible,
// but probably would be less concise due to lack of generic attributes.
//
// It should be possible to validate them automatically somehow, though.
[EventLink(typeof(D), "NumberEvent")]
[EventLink(typeof(E), "NumberEvent")]
void NumberEventHandler(int number)
{ Console.WriteLine("Number received by F: " + number); }
```

The ComponentEntities project contains collections that add themselves as components to themselves or entities added to them, to avoid global singletons. Clone the [bundle repository](https://bitbucket.org/Tamschi/components-bundle) if you want a VS solution with the Components and ComponentsTest (usage examples) projects.

Components' license is LGPL, I didn't license ComponentEntities so far (I set the repository to public just now) but you can probably write something equivalent in about 10 minutes from what I wrote above, should you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like this with DynamicObject.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx

Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic ent = new Entity();
        ent.Components.Add(new Transform() { X = 5, Y = 8 });

        Console.WriteLine(ent.Transform.X);
        ent.Transform.X = 12;
        Console.WriteLine(ent.Transform.X);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Entity : DynamicObject
{
    public List<Component> Components = new List<Component>();

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Components.Count; i++)
        {
            Component component = Components[i];
            if (component.GetType().Name == binder.Name)
            {
                result = component;
                return true;
            }
        }

        result = null;
        return false;
    }
}

class Component
{

}

class Transform : Component
{
    public float X;
    public float Y;
}
```

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**